# I have a ubuntu 12.10 with subversion 1.7.5. When i try to commit a project it returns 500 ISE

Tags: svn, ubuntu-12.10

This is the error that returns the client(versionsapp) when i try to commit.

> Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to POST request for '/svn/ultima_prueba/!svn/me'

I appreciated any help.

The config:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /media/nbserver/nbkup/svn
  SVNListParentPath on
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /media/nbserver/nbkup/passwd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

ErrorLog

```
[Tue Mar 19 11:57:40 2013] [error] [client ip] could not begin a transaction  [500, #13]
[Tue Mar 19 11:57:40 2013] [error] [client ip] Can't open file '/media/nbserver/nbkup/svn/svn_local/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied  [500, #13]
```

Comment: Check and fix permissions for repo. And add more info to question: config, protocol, output of `ls` repository-side, result of `svn ls`

Comment: ... and any relevant log file messages.

Comment: @LazyBadger i updated the question.

Comment: @MrSanders Can you add the rest of the info that was asked for in that comment?

Comment: @nickgrim updated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was an issue about permissions. I just update the group and owner and change chmod.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data *
chmod -R 770 *
```

The result was that now i can commit, create and update projects. Thanks to all that help me.